# Xcode 6 and svn remotes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, svn

I'm relatively new to the mac world so please excuse me if I'm doing something stupid.

I'm trying to get my iPhone app synced with SubVersion. I pushed the app into svn using the vserions trial app.

In Xcode I then added the repository under xcode preferences. I then went to source control -> checkout and pulled the app down from svn to be saved on the local machine. All of this was fine, what I can't suss out is how I push my changes back up to svn (without using versions). If I select commit or push it says no remotes available within the popup. If I use configure under the source control drop down and try to add a new server/remote it simply states it can't connect to the server.

This is what was added within reposiroties: http://serverurl/svn/
App exists at: http://serverurl/svn/reponame/iOS

I would appreciate it if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying I finally managed to resolve this.

When creating the initial project, it creates it with a binding to git. 
In order to get my project correctly committing to svn I had to remove the project from svn, then delete the hidden git folders within my local project, then re-push the project back up to svn, and then check it back out to myself.

This allowed the project to come down to my local machine with 100% ties to svn and no links to git.